# I cant understand why my form button wont call my javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, web

The code below is my javascript code. This for some reason will not function when called by a form button within my HTML code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function calculate(){
    alert('test');
    var JSlength = document.getElementById("length").value;
    var JSwidth = document.getElementById("width").value;
    var JSheight = document.getElementById("height").value;
    var JStotal = document.getElementById("total");

    var JStotal_divide = 0;
    var JStotal_output = 0;

    if (typeof(JSlength) === 'number') {
    if (typeof(JSwidth) === 'number') {
    if (typeof(JSheight) === 'number') {
    if(document.getElementById('international').checked)
    JStotal_divide = (JSlength * JSwidth * JSheight);
    JStotal_output = (JStotal_divide / 5000);

    JStotal.value = JStotal_output;
    } else {
    JStotal_divide = (JSlength * JSwidth * JSheight);
    JStotal_output = (JStotal_divide / 6000);

    JStotal.value = JStotal_output;
    }
    } else {
    window.alert("please only enter numbers.");
    }
    } else {
    window.alert("please only enter numbers.");
    }
    } else {
    window.alert("please only enter numbers.");
    }

    }
    </script>
```

The form below wont interact with the javascript at all, The button gets pressed and nothing happens, I have tried multiple things but for some reason the javascript just doesnt work ? can someone explain why ?

```
<form name="weight_calculate"> <input name="radio"
value="International" id="international" checked="checked" type="radio">International
<input name="radio" value="Domestic" id="domestic" type="radio">Domestic
<div class="header3">Length(cm)</div>
<input name="length" id="length" type="number">
<div class="header3">Width(cm)</div>
<input name="width" id="width" type="number">
<div class="header3">Height(cm)</div>
<input name="height" id="height" type="number">
<div id="divide"> </div>
<input value="Submit" id="submit" onclick="calculate();" type="button">
<div class="header3">Volumetric Weight</div>
<input name="total" id="total" readonly="true"></form>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?  Have you tried using the Developer Tools that come with most browsers (using F12)?

Comment: What doesn't it do? Does it alert the alert? or is it not even doing that?

Comment: Not sure if it's because you've copied/pasted into SO, but your lack of correct indentation will mess with your head!

Comment: Missing curly brace after the 4th if loop condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missing curly brace after `if(document.getElementById('international').checked)`
should be `if(document.getElementById('international').checked){`

Comment: Thanks for that been looking at it all morning and was really frustrating, didnt even notice i had forgot a curly bracket.